# Sending proactive messages to MS teams in a channel

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

We are trying to use proactive messages to send notification in a teams channel whenever some activity happens in the backend system.  I am using the below code:

```
 await msadapter.continueConversation(convRef, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity('proactive hello');
    });
```

in the above code convRef is a reference to conversationReference that is stored into our database. It is obtained when the first time channel is created using a listener on

```
this.onConversationUpdate(async (context, next: () => Promise<void>) => {
}
```

The above technique works just fine when i try it in a group chat. But i  get authorization error in case of channel as below

```
[onTurnError] { Error: Authorization has been denied for this request.
    at new RestError (/workspace/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:1397:28)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:1849:37
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: undefined,
  statusCode: 401,
  request:
   WebResource {
     streamResponseBody: false,
     url:
      'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/19%3A82de560bf7c843b7a6e050fed39db2c5%40thread.tacv2/activities/f%3A48b6e038-a38d-94e3-7907-dcf88ad4484d',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     body:
      '{"type":"message","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"28:a835cf1d-83a8-4ae9-845a-23a68a1df442","name":"FlashCX.ai"},"conversation":{"isGroup":true,"conversationType":"channel","id":"19:82de560bf7c843b7a6e050fed39db2c5@thread.tacv2","tenantId":"04e930f3-0866-4a6d-b07c-a4737e8f9865"},"recipient":{"id":"29:1a-Xb7uPrMwC2XqjMEHCC7ytV2xb2VUCqTA-n_s-k5ZyMCTKIL-ku2XkgbE167D_5ZbmVaqQxJGIQ13vypSqu-A","aadObjectId":"718ab805-860c-43ec-8d4e-4af0c543df75"},"text":"proactive hello hi","inputHint":"acceptingInput","replyToId":"f:48b6e038-a38d-94e3-7907-dcf88ad4484d"}',
     query: undefined,
     formData: undefined,
     withCredentials: false,
     abortSignal: undefined,
     timeout: 0,
     onUploadProgress: undefined,
     onDownloadProgress: undefined,
     operationSpec:
      { httpMethod: 'POST',
        path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}',
        urlParameters: [Array],
        requestBody: [Object],
        responses: [Object],
        serializer: [Serializer] } },
  response:
   { body:
      '{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     status: 401 },
  body:
   { message: 'Authorization has been denied for this request.' } }
```

Doc reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#send-proactive-message

Comment: Are you trying to send proactive message through API? Also Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages)?

Comment: Presumably the bot has been added to the channel?

Comment: Yes Hilton bot is already added to the channel. I remember it adding it once. now in every new channel i create, i can see it showing up by using @botname . Is that enough to say bot is added to the channel or something else needs to be done?

To clarify further i am adding channels to a team and when i go to manage team, under apps tab i see my bot there. hope that is all needed?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT yes i have seen this one. bot.ts file is the one which is storing conversation reference but it gets it from onMessage which gets triggered when someone sends a message to the channel first. I am looking for the way to get some handle when channel is created and use it to send messages in the channel.

Comment: Could you please check this method [Channel Created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#channel-created)?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT yes I have tried that as well. The nice thing with that is that it at least send a message. There are two problems though: 1. it always send the message to the general channel rather in the channel that is created. 2. i dont see how to get a conversation handle for sending messages in future after that. so that kind of does not solve original problem

Comment: When you receive the channel created even t you will receive the new channel information which is created in the channel Info by using that id you can send message.